# driver.find_elements_by_xpath search on only one class

Tags: python, selenium, class, selenium-webdriver, xpath

In my page to **scrape** I have some elements like

```
<a href='xxxx' class='main-class class2 class3'>
```

end others elements like

```
<a href='xxxx' class='main-class class4 class5'>
```

I want to retrieve all these elements, so I did

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='main-class']")
```

but it doesn't retrieve anything. I can't search on one class only.
For the moment, it is working only if I indicate the three classes.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the following XPath:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'main-class')]")
```

This will give you all the elements containing this class